# Why am I getting "Ambiguous column name" in this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee AS emp LEFT JOIN tr_bls_date AS bls ON emp.employee_id=bls.employee_id AND employee_id='".$id."'";
```

Basically, both `emp` and `bls` tables have a common `employee_id` field. I am looking for a certain employee via the employee's ID (`$id`). What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because there are two tables that contains `employee_id` and the server is confused where it will search. To fix the problem, add the source table, eg.

```
ON emp.employee_id = bls.employee_id AND 
   emp.employee_id = ?      // this will search on table employee
```

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO No. There has nothing to do with `SELECT *`. It is on the condition. Test it.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a `left join`, so you should use the alias for `emp`:

```
. . .
emp.employee_id=bls.employee_id AND emp.employee_id=. . .
```

You should use the alias from first table in a `left join` because you are always guaranteed that that has a value.

Comment: It would be ambiguous with an inner join also.

Comment: @DanBracuk . . . Quite true.  The reference is just to which alias should be used.  With a left outer join, it makes a difference.